# Is it possible to make an SDK in Swift and distribute it to apps targeting iOS 6, but only run on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

My company makes an iOS SDK currently programmed in Objective-C. Currently the SDK runs on iOS 6+ (the developer can still deploy to iOS 5, but the SDK will just immediately return from any method called on it).

I'd like to use Swift in our SDK if possible. Is this doable if we require iOS 7 to run the SDK, or would we need to require a deployment target of iOS 7 to do this?